# Найдите, сколько раз каждый символ встречается в тексте, распечатайте результат отсортированный по алфавиту и по частоте символов

Tags: python

```
# С выходом «import this»:
#
# Найдите, сколько раз каждый символ встречается в тексте, распечатайте 
# результат, как описано ниже:
#
# Избегать распечаток кортежа(tuple)
#
# · Сортировать таблицу по алфавиту;
#
# · Сортировать таблицу по частоте символов;
#
# · Перевернуть эти списки по горизонтали;
#
# Ожидаемый вывод:
#
# !=1
# ,=20
# A=13
# c=5
# 
# ,=20
# A=13
# c=5
# !=1
#
# !=1, ,=20, A=13, c=5
#
# ,=20, A=13, c=5, !=1

# Я смог сделать вывод отсортированный по алфавиту

text = """The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"""
```

Comment: удалённый дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/888452/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я посоветовал закрыть старый вопрос и открыть копию, т.к. не хватало голосов для переоткрытия вопроса...

Comment: я не нашел как закрыть только удалить или это одно и тоже?

Comment: @iamsuperoleg, нужно ли учитывать символ перевода строки при подсчете и как его выводить на печать (елси нужно учитывать)?

Comment: не нужно, если нужно то (\n=23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удобнее всего в данном случае воспользоваться [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(text)

res_freq = '\n'.join('{} = {}'.format(tup[0] if tup[0] != "\n" else "\\n", tup[1]) for tup in c.most_common())
```

результат:

```
In [82]: print(res_freq)
  = 124
e = 90
t = 76
i = 50
a = 50
o = 43
s = 43
n = 40
l = 33
r = 32
h = 31
b = 20
\n = 20
u = 20
p = 20
. = 18
y = 17
m = 16
c = 16
d = 16
f = 11
g = 11
x = 6
- = 6
v = 5
, = 4
' = 4
w = 4
T = 3
S = 3
A = 3
I = 3
P = 2
E = 2
k = 2
N = 2
* = 2
Z = 1
B = 1
C = 1
F = 1
R = 1
U = 1
D = 1
! = 1
```

если символ перевода строки (`\n`) учитывать не нужно, то от него лучше избавиться до вызова `Counter()`:

```
c = Counter(text.replace('\n', ''))
```

тогда решение будет выглядеть проще:

```
res_freq = '\n'.join(f'{tup[0]} = {tup[1]}' for tup in c.most_common())
```

горизонтально (с учётом `'\n'`):

```
res_freq_csv = ', '.join('{} = {}'.format(tup[0] if tup[0] != "\n" else "\\n", tup[1]) for tup in c.most_common())

In [84]: print(res_freq_csv)
  = 124, e = 90, t = 76, i = 50, a = 50, o = 43, s = 43, n = 40, l = 33, r = 32, h = 31, b = 20, \n = 20, u = 20, p = 20, . = 18, y = 17, m = 16, c =
 16, d = 16, f = 11, g = 11, x = 6, - = 6, v = 5, , = 4, ' = 4, w = 4, T = 3, S = 3, A = 3, I = 3, P = 2, E = 2, k = 2, N = 2, * = 2, Z = 1, B = 1, C
 = 1, F = 1, R = 1, U = 1, D = 1, ! = 1
```

---

чтобы отсортировать результат по алфавиту:

```
res_abc = '\n'.join('{} = {}'.format(tup[0] if tup[0] != "\n" else "\\n", tup[1]) for tup in sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

In [88]: print(res_abc)
\n = 20
  = 124
! = 1
' = 4
* = 2
, = 4
- = 6
. = 18
A = 3
B = 1
C = 1
D = 1
E = 2
F = 1
I = 3
N = 2
P = 2
R = 1
S = 3
T = 3
U = 1
Z = 1
a = 50
b = 20
c = 16
d = 16
e = 90
f = 11
g = 11
h = 31
i = 50
k = 2
l = 33
m = 16
n = 40
o = 43
p = 20
r = 32
s = 43
t = 76
u = 20
v = 5
w = 4
x = 6
y = 17
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84088/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu--------).

Answer (score 1):

```
for sumbol in sorted(unique_symbol):
    print ("{}={}".format(sumbol, text2.count(sumbol)))
```

Вот это вот не очень здорово, на каждый символ приходится проходить весь текст заново.

Предложение такое:

```
symbols_count = dict()

for s in text:
    # Сюда можно добавить фильтрацию ненужных символов, к примеру пробела
    if s == ' ':
        # Если символов больше одного, то сделать конструкцию с "s in"
        continue

    symbols_count[s] = symbols_count.get(s, 0) + 1
```

В итоге за один проход по тексту получаем словарь где ключ уникальные символы текста, а значения - частота встречаемости. Ну и далее можно производить нужные манипуляции с сортировкой и выводом.

Comment: Спасибо! Подойдет для задания где нужны только количество букв. Согласен, мой вариант много памяти ест.

Comment: Чтобы получить отсортированные данные, можно вызвать sorted, тут уже не сложно )

Памяти то столько же, а CPU много. Но это потом при анализе сложности алгоритма вопросы будут возникать ;)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тоже предложил работать со словарями - логичнее, быстрее и возможность для манёвра есть:

```
text2=''.join(text.split())
freq={}
for letter in text2:
    freq.setdefault(letter,0)
    freq[letter]+=1

for key in sorted(freq):
    print( "{}={}".format(key, freq[key]))

for key in sorted(freq):
    print( "{}={} ".format(key, freq[key]), sep=',', end='')
```